# The alternative to using PETSc's SNES solvers in parallel without using the DMDA methods

Tags: parallel-computing, petsc

I am using the PETSc libraries, in particular using the SNES solver package to solve a nonlinear matrix equation.  Is there a way of parallelising the solution to this problem problem without using the DMDA distributed array methods?

I have looked through the pets manual and the coverage of parallel nonlinear solvers is not well covered.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing about `SNES` that requires `DMDA`.  Create a `Vec` distributed however you would like the state and residual to be distributed, then use `SNESSetFunction()` and (optionally) `SNESSetJacobian()`. See [SNES ex2.c](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/snes/examples/tutorials/ex2.c.html) for an example that does not use `DM`.